# Manually removing CW status should disable auto-conversion to CW unconditionally

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, community-wiki

Currently when a mod reverts the CW status of a post, it will no longer get auto-converted to CW if edits continue to roll in. Apparently this protection against auto-conversion does not hold true when a question and its answers get auto-converted to CW from having too many answers.

I think the behavior should be the same no matter what the trigger is: manually reverted posts should not be auto-converted to CW again for any reason.

Comment: Seems like a moderator might revert a post that was overedited for some legitimate reason, but then be okay with it CWing for overanswering (or the reverse).

Comment: @Joe Wrong tool for the job. If a question is getting too many answers and there isn't a good reason for it (as there is sometimes on Meta.SO) then there is probably an issue with the question and it should be fixed. Also I'd be willing to bet the times that happens in practice is far less than the times when it shouldn't happen, so why not program for the default scenario and let mods handle the exceptions?

Comment: If you're going to make an argument based on statistics... ;)

Comment: I edited your title to make it clearer what you are asking for.  If, that is, I clearly understood what you are asking for. :)  I'm still a  bit unclear about what the second sentence in the first paragraph means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the auto-conversion to CW has been removed for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like that.

I think moderators will only revert the CW status when someone accidentally enabled it, or when someone has been really improving their answer many times, not knowing this might make it CW.

To me, both are very different from the situation where a question gets too many answers, turning *everything* into CW. Hence, I see no reason why an answer that was un-CW'd should be exempt from CW when *everything* else is made CW.